amplify.init not generating amplifyconfiguration file correctly in android studio
amplify.init not generating amplifyconfiguration file correctly in android studio.
It is generating amplifyconfiguration.json file and awsconfiguration.json file with 2 lines of code in it which is:
{
"aws_project_region": "us-east-1"
}
Its was supposed to generate more code in it.
And after running amplify.init it is showing deployment successfully.
Deployment completed.
Deploying root stack demo [ ====================-------------------- ] 2/4
    amplify-demo-dev-6f40f   AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     CREATE_IN_PROGRESS             Mon May 13 2024 01:42:36…

    DeploymentBucket               AWS::S3::Bucket                CREATE_IN_PROGRESS             Mon May 13 2024 01:42:38…

    AuthRole                       AWS::IAM::Role                 CREATE_COMPLETE                Mon May 13 2024 01:42:57…

    UnauthRole                     AWS::IAM::Role                 CREATE_COMPLETE                Mon May 13 2024 01:42:56…

After running the android App:
It is throwing Error:
Could not initialize Amplify
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: No value for region
This is the code for amplifyconfiguration.json:
{
"UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
"Version": "1.0"
}
